# Kill process by filename

Tags: powershell

I have 3 instances of application running from different places. All processes have similar names.

How can I kill process that was launched from specific place?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can get the application path:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*something*"} | Stop-Process -WhatIf
```

That will work for the local machine only. To terminate remote processes:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ExecutablePath LIKE '%something%'" -ComputerName server1 | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

Comment: -WhatIf was just a safety switch :)

Comment: fyi if you match all processes with `-like "*"` and execute the command, it crashes your system

Comment: According to the [Invoke-WmiMethod documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.management/invoke-wmimethod), you should use the new Common Information Model (CIM) cmdlets, introduced in Windows PowerShell 3.0: `Get-CimInstance Win32_Process -Filter "ExecutablePath LIKE '%something%'" -ComputerName server1 | Invoke-CimMethod -Name Terminate`

Comment: I find that `-WhatIf` option can not kill the process for me, I have to use the `-Force` option to kill the process.

Comment: `-WhatIf` is only for checking as `Get-Help Stop-Process -Online` says.

Answer (score 9):

I would like to slightly improve Shay Levy's answer, as it didn't work work well on my setup (version 4 of powershell)

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "*something*"} | Stop-Process -Force -processname {$_.ProcessName}
```

Comment: While this worked for me (as @Shay Levy's answer didn't work) it looks like it's stuck in a loop - you need to cancel the operation (`Ctrl+C` should be enough) to get back to the console

Comment: @Mache I've just added `-Force` flag but I doubt if it would really help. Please take a look also at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40585754/powershell-wont-terminate-hung-process

Comment: What is  -processname ? It is not documented? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: @kuga As I see, it was an alias for -Name: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/stop-process?view=powershell-4.0

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at the `MainModule` property inside of the [`Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx) class (which can be invoked via powershell).

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   if (process.MainModule.FileName == location)
   {
       process.Kill();
   }
}
```

I'd also consider the possible exceptions that can occur while calling this code. This might occur if you're trying to access processes that are no longer present (killed since the last time GetProcess was called) or processes for while you do not have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177004.aspx

```
Stop-Process -processname notepad
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't solve my task.

Comment: Ahh, agreed. I didn't notice you need to kill one not all. You can always kill the process by ID :) Like "kill 1432" or something.

Answer (score 0):

The below command kills processes wherein "something" is part of the path or is a command line parameter. It also proves useful for terminating powershell scripts such as 
`powershell -command c:\my-place\something.ps1` running `something.ps1` from place `c:\my-place`:

```
gwmi win32_process | Where-Object {$_.CommandLine -like "*something*"}  | % { "$(Stop-Process $_.ProcessID)" }
```

The solution works locally on my 64bit Windows 10 machine.