# PowerShell won't terminate hung process

Tags: powershell, process, terminate

I have a scenario where a process is stuck every single Monday morning because of an Oracle database so I tried creating a PowerShell script to run every Monday but regardless of getting an error or not, the process remains.

The line I'm attempting to use for the "kill" is:

```
Get-Process -Name ez0* -ComputerName $server | Stop-Process -Force
```

Tried doing this locally as well without the `-ComputerName`.

I'm not getting any errors from this line with or without the `-Force` it just executes and moves on.

Just doing `Get-Process` works and I can see it but I can't end it with PowerShell. After many attempts I remotely logged on to the server and just right-clicked the process and chose "End task" which worked just fine.

It is an odd process because it's one out of initial 8 (based on cores) and when you stop the service, all but one of the processes is removed save for the one that is hung.

Comment: try ``Invoke-Command $server -Scriptblock {Get-Process -name ez0* | Stop-Process -Force}``

Comment: Using  version 5+, I get following exception when trying to stop a process object from a remote server passed through the pipeline: `stop-process : Cannot stop process "notepad (11720)" because of the following err
or: Feature is not supported for remote machines.`

Comment: I will attempt the wmi way on Monday to see how things go but this is not a remote issues wince the local test was the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using:

```
$termproc = (get-wmiobject -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name like 'ez0%'"
$termproc.terminate()
```

You could also just do the below if you don't want to check the processes in the variable first.

```
(get-wmiobject -ComputerName $server -Class Win32_Process -Filter "name like 'ez0%'").terminate()
```

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Thanks for the wmiobject solution! For some reason the terminate command grabbing the process as wmiobject worked wheras the `Stop-Process` did not.

Comment: No worries Patrik. Glad it worked. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Not working in powershell 7