# Try to remotely kill a process using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, wmi, powershell-remoting

I have followed the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10265869/kill-process-by-filename) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14952833/get-wmiobject-win32-process-computername-gets-error-access-denied-code-0x8) to write a PowerShell script that remotely kills a process:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "Name='myapp.exe'" -ComputerName remotecomputername | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

The above works when I execute it on my machine, but when it's run remotely, targeting my machine by a user setup as per the instructions on the second link, the command fails silently. Any advice on what's wrong / how I can debug this?

Comment: Are you on the same network. Looks like just at glance you need to pass credentials using -credential

Comment: @ArcSet Yes on the same network, and my colleague running it remotely is setup on my computer to be able to execute commands via WMI (second link above). Do I still need to pass credentials in this case?

Comment: Yes please use the -credential

Comment: Is there a way of using Active Directory to provide authentication so that a user doesn't need to provide a password at the prompt? I had hoped that setting the user up for WMI would avoid that.

Comment: I believe this may provide a solution to pass credentials: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6239647/using-powershell-credentials-without-being-prompted-for-a-password/6240319

Comment: Is the user a domain admin, or just a local admin on the PC?  If they're just local, they need to specify the PC name as the domain when providing credentials.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score -1):

As described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692772.aspx):

> Generally speaking, any operation that WMI can perform on the local
>   computer can also be performed on a remote computer where you have
>   local administrator privileges

Once I setup a user with admin privileges to use WMI on my computer they can execute the script remotely without passing credentials.

Comment: This is not an answer and should be an edit to your question.  Also note, *generally speaking*

Comment: Why is it not an answer? I needed to remotely kill a process using WMI, this is how I did it.